# Opening pdf file Error: This file could not be accessed Check the location or the network and try again

Tags: android, pdf

Hi inside of the adapter I am displaying a button to view PDf .When I am try to click on that button it is giving me this error.below One is complete what i have tried in my application.

Can any one help me resolve this issue.

```
This file could not be accessed Check the location or the network and try again.//error

holder.pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        opportunity.getPdf_link());
               // Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                Uri pdf = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

                Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(pdf, "application/pdf");
                pdfOpenintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


                try {
                    mContext.startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    // handle no application here....
                }
            }

        });
```

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Or, if you are really sure that you need that flag, switch to `addFlags()` rather than `setFlags()`. As it stands, `setFlags()` is *replacing* the flag that you added in the previous line... and that flag (`FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`) is much more important.

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19; index=20
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1999)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:748)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)

Comment: @jyothisri: You must have made some other change as well. Your `getUriForFile()` call occurs before the line I recommended that you remove or alter.

Comment: which line i have to remove

Comment: can you help me